# Imported instance has no "this" reference in Nuxt.js

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, nuxt.js, nuxtjs

```js
// @/states/app.js
import Vue from 'vue'

class AppState {
  constructor() {
    this.state = Vue.observable({
      onboard
    })
  }

  async getWallet() {
    await this.state.onboard.walletSelect()
  }
}

export { AppState }
export default new AppState()
```

```js
// my-plugin.js
import Vue from 'vue'
import AppState from '@/states/app'

Vue.prototype.$app = AppState
```

Simplified version of my .vue file

```html
// default.vue
<template>
  <button @click="$app.getWallet">Connect Wallet</button>
</template>

<script>
beforeMount() {
  if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development') {
    window.vm = this
  }
}
</script>
```

If I run `vm.$app.getWallet()` in my Chrome console, it works as expected. However, if I click on the button in `default.vue`, I get a `Cannot read property 'state' of null` error page from Nuxt.